# ASP.NET MVC Pass datetime as query

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How would I pass a datetime e.g. `01/01/2011 21:01:34` as a query string?

I am building a theatre booking site and when viewing performances I currently pass the Show and Venue but also need to pass the date (as this is the unique part of the performance)

The ActionResult looks like so:

```
public ActionResult Details(String name, String venue, String date)
{
    return View(_repository.performanceDetails(name, venue, date));
}
```

But the `performanceDate` wont work because it's a datetime data type! What I need to do is REMOVE the time part of the data e.g. `00:00:00` and somehow pass the remaining data as a string that I can use to compare against like so:

```
public PerformanceDetails performanceDetails(String name, String venue, String date)
{
    var PerformanceDetails = (from s in _db.PerformanceDetails
                              where s.show == name && 
                                    s.venue == venue && 
                                    s.performanceDate == date
                              select s).First();
    return PerformanceDetails;
}
```

Here is a sample link:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("View Details", "Details", "Performances", 
                    new { 
                        name = item.show, 
                        venue = item.venue, 
                        date = item.performanceDate }, 
                    new {@class = "button"}) %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting your date on the querystring in a format something like this:

```
item.performanceDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

This will give you a URL like (if you're not using routes):

```
http://foo/Performance/Details?name=someName&venue=someVenue&date=31-Mar-2011
```

This is helpful because you'll want to avoid slashes in your date on the querystring, and you'll want to be explicit about month/date placement (the whole US and UK). Suggest using numbers for date, and alpha characters for month.

In your ActionMethod, you can then simply `TryParse()` or `Parse()` the incoming value.

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

In your LINQ query you can do something like this:

```
&& s.performanceDate == dt
```

So to put it all together:

```
public ActionResult Details(String name, String venue, String date)
{
    DateTime dt;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out dt))
    {
        return View(_repository.performanceDetails(name, venue, dt));    
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Error", "The value passed in date isn't a date value.");
    }
}

public PerformanceDetails performanceDetails(String name, String venue, DateTime dt)
{
    var PerformanceDetails = (from s in _db.PerformanceDetails
                              where s.show == name && 
                                    s.venue == venue && 
                                   s.performanceDate == dt.Date                  
                              select s).First();
    return PerformanceDetails;

}

<%= Html.ActionLink("View Details", "Details", "Performances", 
                new { name = item.show , 
                      venue = item.venue, 
                      date = item.performanceDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") }, 
                new {@class = "button"}) %>
```

Comment: I'm **NOT** routing urls though so I currently have urls like `/?name=Macbeth&venue=Playhouse&date=02/01/2011`

Comment: @p.campbell Sorry I'm a bit confused (quite late here in the UK too) any chance you could edit my three pieces of code with your idea so I can fully see what you mean. I think I do but I'm worried about blowing up my app. **MUCH APPRECIATED!**

Comment: I get the following error: `The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.` and it blows up in my repository (so the second piece of code) any ideas what the problem is and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: it's an MDF in the App_Data folder it's a datetime and it's NOT nullable. thanks

Comment: Get this error now: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: YES! Thanks so much :P Was getting really depressed then. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, the argument to your Action method should be a DateTime type, not a string. You should make sure that your query string argument is formatted using ISO 8601 Extended Format (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), for example: 2011-10-17T12:35:00.

The default binder will convert that string to a date without any problem. I found that you need two digits each for hh:mm:ss, that is, use leading zeros for numbers below ten. You can omit the milliseconds though, and the time zone 'Z' specifier.

Now that you have a full date and time, you can simply use the date portion for database lookups using mydate.Date.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can do this.  One way is the way Cameron suggests.  Another way would be to convert the date to a numeric number, such as ticks, then pass this numeric value on your URL and convert it back in your Action method.

```
Int64 ticks = dateOfShow.Ticks;

DateTime newDateOfShow = new DateTime(ticks);
```